# Remove duplicates in Pair RDD based on Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with multiple rows which looks like below.

`val row = [(String, String), (String, String, String)]`

The value is a sequence of Tuples. In the tuple, the last String is a timestamp and the second one is category. I want to filter this sequence based on maximum timestamp for each category.

```
(A,B)       Id      Category        Timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------
(123,abc)   1       A              2016-07-22 21:22:59+0000
(234,bcd)   2       B              2016-07-20 21:21:20+0000
(123,abc)   1       A              2017-07-09 21:22:59+0000
(345,cde)   4       C              2016-07-05 09:22:30+0000
(456,def)   5       D              2016-07-21 07:32:06+0000
(234,bcd)   2       B              2015-07-20 21:21:20+0000
```

I want one row for each of the categories.I was looking for some help on **getting the row with the max timestamp for each category**. The result I am looking to get is

```
(A,B)       Id      Category        Timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------
(234,bcd)   2       B              2016-07-20 21:21:20+0000
(123,abc)   1       A              2017-07-09 21:22:59+0000
(345,cde)   4       C              2016-07-05 09:22:30+0000
(456,def)   5       D              2016-07-21 07:32:06+0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Given input `dataframe` as

```
+---------+---+--------+------------------------+
|(A,B)    |Id |Category|Timestamp               |
+---------+---+--------+------------------------+
|[123,abc]|1  |A       |2016-07-22 21:22:59+0000|
|[234,bcd]|2  |B       |2016-07-20 21:21:20+0000|
|[123,abc]|1  |A       |2017-07-09 21:22:59+0000|
|[345,cde]|4  |C       |2016-07-05 09:22:30+0000|
|[456,def]|5  |D       |2016-07-21 07:32:06+0000|
|[234,bcd]|2  |B       |2015-07-20 21:21:20+0000|
+---------+---+--------+------------------------+
```

You can do the following to get the result `dataframe` you require

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val requiredDataframe = df.orderBy($"Timestamp".desc).groupBy("Category").agg(first("(A,B)").as("(A,B)"), first("Id").as("Id"), first("Timestamp").as("Timestamp"))
```

You should have the `requiredDataframe` as

```
+--------+---------+---+------------------------+
|Category|(A,B)    |Id |Timestamp               |
+--------+---------+---+------------------------+
|B       |[234,bcd]|2  |2016-07-20 21:21:20+0000|
|D       |[456,def]|5  |2016-07-21 07:32:06+0000|
|C       |[345,cde]|4  |2016-07-05 09:22:30+0000|
|A       |[123,abc]|1  |2017-07-09 21:22:59+0000|
+--------+---------+---+------------------------+
```

You can do the same by using `Window` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Category").orderBy($"Timestamp".desc)
df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === lit(1)).drop("rank")
```

Comment: I want to perform these on an RDD and not a dataframe. So I was wondering if that needs to be done a different way?